# Frames around menus in GTK3 apps - compton

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, compton

I have Xubuntu 16.04, fully updated, on a 64bit machine.

I had a screen tearing issue, so I installed compton for compositing. Then the issues began with frames showing up around gtk3 apps, such as transmission et al.

Neither [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/2qk7c3/with_i3_compton_and_gtk3_make_rounded_corners_on/cn6zjme/) nor [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852137/xfwm4-compton-problems-with-gtk3-applications#852211) helped.

The latter just made everything flat. No grapic goodies at all.

Any ideas what next?

Thanks,

Comment: A screenshot would be useful don't you think?!

Comment: They were already in the threads i linked. Opening them would be also useful, don't you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I did something wrong when trying the first of the aboveposted solutions. It works now!

So, what you need to do is:

edit the file ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css (if it doesn't exist, create it).

In it, paste:

```
.window-frame, .window-frame:backdrop {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 black;
 border-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
}

.titlebar {
 border-radius: 0;
}
```

Voila, the annoying glassed frames should be gone, and compton should render some nice eyecandy without glitches.